# React + d3: Passing onHover function to all grouped elements in an SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am creating an interactive map using React and d3. I am trying to pass an onHover function to all the grouped elements within my SVG illustration, which I used to set the state to the id of the grouped element. Here is the code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyMap from './components/MyMap'
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.onHover = this.onHover.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      hover : "none"
    }
  }

  onHover(d){
    console.log("Hovering over element: " + d.id)
    this.setState({
      hover: d.id
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <MyMap onHover={this.onHover} hover={this.state.hover} />
  }
}

export default App;
```

MyMap.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './map-style.css'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

class MyMap extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.prepareSvg = this.prepareSvg.bind(this);
  }

  prepareSvg(){
    const node = this.node;
    d3.select(node).select('#the_map').selectAll('g').on('mouseover', this.props.onHover);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.prepareSvg();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.prepareSvg();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
       <svg ref={node => this.node = node} className="svg-container" viewBox="0 0 787 1756">
         <g id="the_map">
         <g id="place_1">...</g>
         <g id="place_2">...</g>
         ...
         </g>
       </svg>
      </div>
    }
}

export default MyMap;
```

When I go to hover over an element, the console message triggers, but "d" is undefined. How do I pass the id of the group I am hovering over to this callback function?

I've referenced the code found in this example to get this far:
https://github.com/emeeks/d3_in_action_2/tree/master/chapter9/reactd3

I can provide more code or context if needed.

Answer (score 0):

"d" comes from the data chain function if the data is an array (iterable)...

> .data(data)

or attribute if not an array (string/object etc)

> .attr("d", data)

try something like this...

```
  prepareSvg(){
    const node = this.node,
            data = "some data"
    d3.select(node).select('#the_map').selectAll('g').attr("d", data).on('mouseover', this.props.onHover);
  }
```

That is how "d" gets to everything after in the chain... like hover